# Asigning Default Values To List Of Binary Tree Elements - Missing Constructor?

Tags: c#, tree

Alright, I'm having hard time figuring our how I can assign default values to the elements of the list (Trees and nodes) so I don't get NullReferenceException.

The basic idea of the code is:
List contains from Trees, each tree contains 2 nodes, each node contains 2 sub-nodes.
[Link to visual representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEKVR.jpg)

Each node contains Name(string) and Size(String)

code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Tree> TreeList = new List<Tree>();

        Tree newtree = new Tree();
        Branch newbrach = new Branch();

        // user can add any number of new trees to the list
        // when tree is added, user can edit the default values of the tree
        //.....
        case 2:
              TreeList.Add(newtree); break; // Adds new Tree to The list
        //.....

        foreach (Tree item in TreeList)
        {
        //loop to print out all values
        }
    }
 } 

 class Tree
 {
     public Branch Left = new Branch();
     public Branch Right = new Branch();
 }

class Area
{
    public string Name;
    public string Size;
} 

class Branch
{
    public Area Area = new Area();
    public Branch Right;
    public Branch Left;
}
```

I must be missing a constructor of some sort, because if I'm adding new tree to the list and I'm trying to directly edit it via List[i].Left.Area.Name = ... I get NullReferenceExeption.

Basically, what I want is - whenever I add a new Tree to the list, each node should have it's default values set to "empty" or something that can be manually changed later by accessing them from loop and, for example, list has 2 trees, I want to edit the values of first tree -> List[0].Right.Area.Name = "newname", first tree -> List[0].Right.Area.Size = "1000", List[0].Left.Left.Area = .... and so on.

Comment: You left out the essential part, how is `List[i]` filled in?

Comment: There's a selection of actions in the program, when user wants to add a new tree to the list, it executes part of the code that creates a new tree , Tree newtree = new Tree(); add adds it to the list TreeList.Add(newtree); The idea is when the tree is added to the list, I should be able to edit it, however, I can't.

Comment: Make a minimal but complete example. Your code looks like it should work so the problem is in the parts you 'simplified'.